# Simple regular expression for all strings over $\{0,1\}^*$ not ending in $01$

Tags: regular-expressions

Give a regular expression for the language of all strings over $\{0,1\}^*$
not ending in $01$.

$\in | 0 | 1 | (0|1)^* | (11|00|10)$

The solution above was provided by my professor but I'm not convinced that it is correct. Would the $(0|1)^*$ be any sting over the alphabet $\{0,1\}^* $and therefore could end in $01$. I think that is should be $(0|1)^*(11|00|10)$. Am I correct or am I missing something?

Comment: What you are saying is correct.

Comment: Your proposal is not right: it misses the string "1", for example.

Comment: The problem with the expression given by your teacher is that the bar after the star should not be there.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment:** Yes, you are correct. May be there were a typo.

---

**Explanation:**

Draw DFA that accepts all strings over $\{0,1\}^*$ ending with $01$, then complement that DFA. That DFA will be:

[image]

Now, you can identify reqular expression of this DFA. Since, there are three final states, So, All strings not ending in $01$:

$$\in + 0 + 1 + (0 + 1)^*
(00 + 10 + 11):$$

The expression  $\in+0+1$ describes the strings with length zero or one, and
the expression $(0 + 1)^*(00 + 10 + 11)$ describes the strings with length two
or more.

---

**References:**

[Ref_1](http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/electrical-engineering-and-computer-science/6-035-computer-language-engineering-spring-2010/exams/MIT6_035S10_quiz01.pdf)

[Ref_2](http://www.cs.rpi.edu/courses/fall00/modcomp3/sol3.pdf)

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26521108/regular-expression-for-automata-for-strings-that-do-not-end-in-01

https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/3368/nfa-for-binary-words-that-do-not-end-in-10