# Grammar for language not ending on "01"

Tags: regular-language, formal-grammar

I want to write a grammar for a language not ending on "01". I found the regular expression here:

[regular expression](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1879717/simple-regular-expression-for-all-strings-over-0-1-not-ending-in-01)

I tried the following:

```
S-->1S11| 0S10|01S00|00|10|11|lambda
```

Somebody please guide me.

Zulfi.

Comment: Assuming you meant epsilon (i.e. the empty string) instead of lambda, you are getting there. Two hints: (1) what about strings of length 1? (2) for strings of length 2+, consider creating a new non-terminal symbol. (Note that the regular expression given in the question is wrong - the regular expression given in the answer below is correct).

Comment: This is the regular expression provided in the answer of the above link. Please guide me what's wrong with this: epsilon + 0 + 1 + (0 + 1)^*(00 + 10 + 11):

Comment: @roundsquare some texts do use $\lambda$ instead of $\epsilon$ for the empty string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the regular expression:

$\epsilon+0+1+(0+1)^*(00+10+11)$

There are four possibilities: (1) empty string; (2) $0$; (3) $1$; and (4) longer strings.

We can directly replicate this in the grammar

$S \rightarrow \epsilon|0|1|T$

$T \rightarrow 0T|1T|00|10|11$

As you can see, $S$ can *directly* do the first three possibilities or do the fourth possibility using $T$. $T$ builds up bigger strings by allowing any number of $0$'s and $1$'s and then ending with either $00$, $10$, or $11$ (to prevent it from ending with $01$).